# Identify device in windows hook

Tags: c++, winapi, keylogger

I'm trying to write background app for log specific scanned codes via baracode scanner (connected as keyboard). I wrote code and it works fine, but I want to define device which can send input to my app

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...
    hhkLowLevelKybd = ::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC)LowLevelKeyboardProc, 0, 0);
    ...
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    here i need check device

    // check and log code
}
```

thanks

Comment: If you need device information alongside the input events, you have to use [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx).

Comment: If I use RegisterRawInputDevices and capture INPUT message, I've got correct device, **but**, my callback LowLevelKeyboardProc called early than I receive INPUT message(

Comment: Why are you using a low-level hook at all?  It does not provide any device information. If you need to handle events from a specific device, use ONLY the Raw Input events, DO NOT use a low-level hook. The Raw Input messages provide you with the entered keyboard data. Plus, the Raw Input API lets you register specific devices to send events to specific HWNDs, so when you do receive the input messages, you already know which device they come from without having to figure it out from the message data. I think you are making things too complicated for what you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: I use low-level hook, because I need prevent input some symbols, so, may be exists more easy way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all, I found the way to solve this - this is library [interception](https://github.com/oblitum/Interception)